# xarray - select data in a DataArray with arbitrary labels from a numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have a DataArray called `da_ffdi`. It contains three dimensions: `time`, `latitude` and `longitude`. The time dimension has a continuous set of hourly labels from 1972-01-20T00:00:00 to 2020-06-30T00:00:00.

```
xarray.DataArray
'FFDI'    time: 424680    latitude: 148    longitude: 244

Coordinates:

    latitude    (latitude)    float32           -39.2 -39.163948 ... -33.9
    longitude   (longitude)   float32           140.8 140.83786 ... 149.96214 150.0
    time        (time)        datetime64[ns]    1972-01-20 ... 2020-06-30T23:00:00
                              array(['1972-01-20T00:00:00.000000000', '1972-01-20T01:00:00.000000000',
                                    '1972-01-20T02:00:00.000000000', ..., '2020-06-30T21:00:00.000000000',
                                    '2020-06-30T22:00:00.000000000', '2020-06-30T23:00:00.000000000'],
                                    dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I have a numpy array called `np_dates`.

```
array(['2013-03-27', '2019-03-25', '2013-04-27', '2013-03-21',
       '2020-05-30', '2018-03-18', '2019-11-21', '2018-03-17',
       '2013-04-28', '2008-03-14', '2014-02-09', '2013-05-03',
       '2013-05-04', '2015-05-05', '2014-07-31', '2003-06-06',
       '2018-02-14', '2018-04-14', '1972-04-23', '2014-01-01',
       '1975-02-08', '2008-04-02', '1979-02-15', '1975-03-02',
       '2001-02-21', '2006-08-16', '2001-03-16', '2018-03-25',
       '2009-02-07', '2008-04-03', '2016-05-01', '1990-01-30',
       '1998-03-22', '1982-05-19', '1986-03-20', '1987-11-23',
       '2019-12-20', '1998-02-26', '1985-03-04', '2018-05-04'])
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to select all the data from `da_ffdi` where the `time` labels from `np_dates`.

I ran:

```
da_ffdi.sel(time=np_dates)
```

This raised an error:

```
KeyError: "not all values found in index 'time'"
```

How to fix this? Can this be achieved by running the `where` function?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67058174/5997555) helps

Answer (score 0):

[`DataArray.isin`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html?highlight=isin#selecting-values-with-isin); from the docs:

```py
lookup = xr.DataArray([-1, -2, -3, -4, -5], dims=["x"])

da.where(lookup.isin([-2, -4]), drop=True)
Out[36]: 
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2)>
array([2., 4.])
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```